# Forcing iPhone WWAN interface to wake up when I try to connect to server

Tags: iphone, connection, 3g, wwan

Is there an API call I can call to wake up an iPhone's 3G / WiFi connection before connecting a socket to a remote server, short of doing something stupid like loading a webpage using [NSData loadContentsFromUrl:@"www.example.com"] to kick off the connection?

I know there's a flag for keeping a persistent WiFi connection, but it doesn't seem to apply to 3G. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have a similar problem using phonegap with ios. When the wifi is 'sleeping' it will not wake up when I make an ajax call to the server. Therefore the ajax call will fail. When I quickly go into the browser to go to a random webpage the wifi wakes up. Then when I go back to my app the ajax call works. Any ideas?